# Guess the number in Python - decreasing range problem

Tags: python

I want to write a simple guessing game in Python. But I want to have additional feature that **the range** (in which there is correct number) **is decreased after each guess by user**. My code is as follows:

```
com_number = 49
user_number = input('Enter the number from 0 to 100: ')
user_number = int(user_number)
check = 0
number_min = 0
number_max = user_number
while check == 0:
    if user_number == com_number:
        print(f'Congratulations!')
        check = 1
    elif user_number > com_number:
        number_max = user_number
        user_number = int(input(f'Too high... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}\n'))
    else:
        number_min = user_number
        user_number = int(input(f'Too low... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}\n'))
```

Example output from the script:

```
Enter the number from 0 to 100: 89
Too high... 0 < ? < 89
75
Too high... 0 < ? < 75
12
Too low... 12 < ? < 75
46
Too low... 46 < ? < 75
66
Too high... 46 < ? < 66
58
Too high... 46 < ? < 58
52
Too high... 46 < ? < 52
47
Too low... 47 < ? < 52
50
Too high... 47 < ? < 50
48
Too low... 48 < ? < 50
49
Congratulations!
```

So as you can see **when the first guess is higher than correct number** (in this case 89 > 49) the script works great just as I expected.

Another example output from the script:

```
Enter the number from 0 to 100: 68
Too high... 0 < ? < 68
30
Too low... 30 < ? < 68
45
Too low... 45 < ? < 68
50
Too high... 45 < ? < 50
49
Congratulations!
```

So, **when the second guess is lower than correct number** (in this case 30 < 49) the script also works correctly.

But the problem is **when the first guess is lower than correct number**. In this case the script changes also value of 'number_max' variable in print() statement, which is totally incorrect. Please check below:

```
Enter the number from 0 to 100: 45
Too low... 45 < ? < 45
```

or

```
Enter the number from 0 to 100: 21
Too low... 21 < ? < 21
```

I have no idea why it works this way...

Comment: Try changing the initialization of `number_max` from `number_max = user_number` to `number_max = 100` - before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code instead:

```
com_number = 49
number_min, number_max = 0, 100

print(f'Enter number in between {number_min} < ? < {number_max}')
while True:
    user_number = int(input())

    if user_number < number_min or user_number > number_max:
        print(f'Number not in range... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}')
    elif user_number == com_number:
        print('Congratulations!')
        break
    elif user_number > com_number:
        number_max = user_number
        print(f'To high... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}')
    else:
        number_min = user_number
        print(f'To low... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}')
```

I've simplified some of your code as it was unnecessary and fixed a bug. I'll explain my changes:

```
# previously
check = 0
while check == 0:
  # ...
  check = 1

# now
while True:
  # ...
  break
```

`while True` generates an infinite loop which can be interrupted simply by adding `break` wherever certain criteria are met and does not have to run any longer (when the user guessed correctly).

```
# previously
number_min = 0
number_max = user_number

# now
number_min, number_max = 0, 100
```

`a, b = 1, 2` assigns two variables at once (`a = 1` and `b = 2`). `number_max = user_number` doesn't make any sense and **is the reason for the weird behavior you've experienced**.

```
if user_number < number_min or user_number > number_max:
```

Is another *edge case* which rejects invalid user input.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set `number_max = user_number` before the loop.
A way to fix the problem would be to write an `if` statement or simply to specify `number_max = 100` instead.

```
com_number = 49
user_number = input('Enter the number from 0 to 100: ')
user_number = int(user_number)
check = 0
number_min, number_max = 0, 100

while check == 0:
    if user_number == com_number:
        print(f'Congratulations!')
        check = 1
    elif user_number > com_number:
        number_max = user_number
        user_number = int(input(f'Too high... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}\n'))
    else:
        number_min = user_number
        user_number = int(input(f'Too low... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# lets have a random number generated instead of pre defining it.
import random
com_number = random.randint(1, 101)
user_number = int(input("Guess the number from 1 - 100 : "))
max_number = 100 # define max_number = 100 instead of o
min_number = 0
while user_number != com_number:
    if user_number == com_number:
        user_number = com_number
    elif user_number > com_number:
        max_number = user_number
        user_number = int(input(f"Too high... {0} < ? < {max_number}\n"))
    elif user_number < com_number:
        min_number = user_number
        highest = 100
        user_number = int(input(f"Too low...{min_number} < ? < {max_number}\n"))
if user_number == com_number:
    print("Congratulations.")
# I printed congratulations outside the loop because the loop will terminate after u 
#  guessed the number.
```

Comment: This is not correct: It can not be user_number = int(input(f"Too high... {0} < ? < {max_number}\n")). It has to be user_number = int(input(f"Too high... {min_number} < ? < {max_number}\n")). Otherwise check this out:

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was so obvious... I can not believe I missed this declaration before loop :). But I found another issue in this code. Please check the output:

```
Enter the number from 0 to 100: 51
Too high... 0 < ? < 51
99
Too high... 0 < ? < 99
```

And this is wrong, it is obvious that in this case the range should remain from 0 to 51 (even if the user entered 99 number)

So I had to add another conditions. I have noticed all of your suggestions and my final script looks as follows.

```
import random
def guess():
    max_range = int(input('Set the maximum range you want to guess the number:'))
    com_number = random.randrange(0,max_range)
    user_number = int(input(f'Enter the number from 0 to {max_range}:'))
    i = 1
    number_min = 0
    number_max = max_range
    while  True:
            if user_number == com_number:
                break
            elif user_number > com_number:
                if user_number >= number_max:
                    number_max = number_max
                else:
                    number_max = user_number
                user_number = int(input(f'Too high... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}\n'))
                i = i + 1
            else:
                if user_number < number_min:
                    number_min = number_min
                else:
                    number_min = user_number
                user_number = int(input(f'Too low... {number_min} < ? < {number_max}\n' ))
                i = i + 1
    print(f'Congratulations! You guessed the number at the {i} time.')
guess()
```

And now the script works as I wanted from the beginning. Thank you for the help.

But I wonder if there is a way to make it simpler and achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

This was awesome question. This is how I solved it: I simply call the same function again until we get desired outcome and updating the range:

btw:if you are using Python <3.6, change the f-formatting from f'{min} and {max}' to '{min} and {max}'.format(min=min,max=max)

```
import random

def guess(min,max):
    n =  int(input('Guess number: '))
    if choice > n >= min:
        min = n
        print(f'Low: {min} > ? > {max}')
        guess(min,max)

    elif choice < n <= max:
        max = n
        print(f'High: {min} > ? > {max}')
        guess(min,max)

    else:
        if choice == n:
            print(f'Bravo! You got it {choice}')
        else:
            if choice > n:
                print(f'Still Low: {min} > ? > {max}: check the scale!')
                guess(min,max)

            elif choice < n:
                print(f'Still High: {min} > ? > {max}: check the scale!')
                guess(min,max)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    choice = random.randint(1,101)
    min,max = 0, 100
    guess(min,max)
```